# click function not working on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used below code to click function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#tblGrantListtable_filter input").hide();
     $("#vserch").click(function () {
     $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").show();
   });    

   $("#tblGrantListtable_filter input").insertBefore(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder label");
   $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").attr('id', 'sample6')
   $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").addClass("mdl-textfield__input");
   $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").removeClass("form-control");
   $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").removeClass("input-sm");
   $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").removeAttr("placeholder");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$(document).on('click',"#vserch",function () {
            $(".mdl-textfield__expandable-holder input").show();
        });
```